# Caveats for using Guava's EventBus

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

From the [docs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained)

> It is not a general-purpose publish-subscribe system, nor is it intended for interprocess communication

What do they mean by saying it's not a general-purpose publish-subscribe system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand this is within a JVM only, publish/subscribe is usually between processes residing in potentially different places: like one JVM talking to another, suppose one Spring application publishing events that are to be consumed by another Spring application, residing in entirely different places.

Answer (score 1):

It's better explained in the bottom of [the EventBusExplained page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained):

> ## Why can't I do <magic thing> with EventBus?
>
> **EventBus is designed to
>   deal with a large class of use cases really, really well**. We prefer
>   hitting the nail on the head for most use cases to doing decently on
>   all use cases.
>
> Additionally, **making EventBus extensible** -- and making it useful and
>   productive to extend, while still allowing ourselves to make additions
>   to the core EventBus API that don't conflict with any of your
>   extensions -- **is an extremely difficult problem**.
>
> If you really, really need magic thing X, that EventBus can't
>   currently provide, you should file an issue, and then design your own
>   alternative.

(Emphasis mine.)

Compare EventBus to Kafka for example -- the latter is much more extensible but also more complex.